# VUE3 - Open Bootstrap Modal By Image Click Without JQuery On MultiPage / Component

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, vuejs3

I try to use VUE3 and Bootstrap to open a Modal by clicking one of those two images.

I created 3 Components.

1. Left DIV (Image)
2. Right DIV (Image)
3. Modal to open

Now, i want to click on one of those images and open the modal.
At Singlepage it works. But now i am using Components.

How do i listen in the Component "ModalContact" to the clickevent in other Components?

I uploaded the complete package to github: https://github.com/Gismo1337/wtf-i-am-doing-here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Vue 2 and the Vue CLI, I created a couple of Single File Components to demonstrate how to open and close a Bootstrap 4 Modal without jQuery, wrapping the modal in it's own component.

Although this is not using Vue 3, you should be able to port it.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h4>Bootstrap Modal Parent</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="showModal">Open Bootstrap Modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <bootstrap-modal-no-jquery v-if="displayModal" @close-modal-event="hideModal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import BootstrapModalNoJquery from './BootstrapModalNoJquery.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      BootstrapModalNoJquery
    },
    data() {
      return {
        displayModal: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.displayModal = true;
      },
      hideModal() {
        this.displayModal = false;
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

BootstrapModalNoJquery.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="bootstrap-modal-no-jquery">
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveChanges">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="closeModal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      closeModal() {
        this.$emit('close-modal-event');
      },
      saveChanges() {
        this.closeModal();
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  /* Override default value of 'none' */
  .modal {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```